# Maintaining file of object properties in Watin + Visual Studio

Tags: watin

I am working with Watin and maintaining excel file for listing object properties.
It takes lot of time to when I read object properties from excel file.
Is there any other way to store these object properties at centralised location so that we can refer object properties and change in any object will get reflected in all TCs using this object.

In short content of excel file is as follow:

Menu----------------------------id

username_txtfield------------uname

password_txtfield------------ pass

ok_webedit-------------------submit

Answer (score 0):

You can use `appSettings` in `App.config` for managing key-value pairs - access is very fast.

You'll also want to create a data access class that abstracts away where the settings are actually being stored so that if (when?) you change where you properties are being stored you just change one class rather than going through your entire codebase making changes.